# Razor convetions

Tags: c#, razor

I have been working a Razor templeting system but am running into a consistent syntax error. In many of my .cshtml files I am swapping between .cs and .js multiple times on one line of code which causes the intellisense get confused.

Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="dtscript">
///...
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ColumnDefs))
{
    @:columnDefs: @model.ColumnDefs,
}
///...
</script>
```

In the above line the trailing comma after @ColumnDefs is a syntax error, however when the .cshtml file compiles and I render the template the rendered code is correct. This syntax error holds for alternate ways of generating the code...

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ColumnOrder))
{
    <text>order: @model.ColumnOrder</text>,
}
//or
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ColumnOrder))
{
    <text>order: @model.ColumnOrder,</text>
}
```

Since the template generates the correct view I have been slow about addressing the syntax error, but I am getting tired of all of the red squiggly lines. So my question is what is the correct way to splice .cs and .js to avoid incorrectly reported syntax errors throughout the razor file.

Update: 
Let me expand on this scenario a little. There is no controller, this system is a stand alone library. The templeting system is product agnostic and is part of a Domain Specific Language for common plugins. The @model.ColumnDefs is actually a json object that renders into the following code.

```
columnDefs: [{"sortable":false,"targets":[0,3]},
  {"visible":false,"targets":[0,7]},
  {"searchable":false,"targets":[0]},
  {"name":"Id","targets":0},
  {"name":"Email","targets":1},
  {"name":"Name","targets":2},
  {"name":"IsAdmin","targets":3},
  {"name":"Salary","targets":4},
  {"name":"Position","targets":5},
  {"name":"Hired","targets":6},
  {"name":"Number","targets":7}],
```

It can not be wrapped in "" or '' otherwise the plugin is not able to parse the code.

Comment: Simple answer - don't mix you're JavaScript into your razor! This is just going to make your code horrible to maintain. Instead create a JSON object and return it from a `GET` request, use that in your JavaScript.

Comment: While I agree with your answer Ian this method is the only method I have been able to come up with that meets our requirements. I am using JSON objects behind the scenes, but as the generated code is dynamic based on usage I have no static code to rely upon. The users define the modes in their views (through a fluently configured progressive interface) and this library returns to them the rendered .js code.

Comment: Take a long hard think and see if you can refactor it before continuing down this route

Comment: Contrary to what others think, Razor is not just a MVC View Engine, it is a templating engine first. OP, I think this is just a case of OCD :-) If its generating the correct code, ignore the squiggles and move on.

Comment: LOL yes I suppose that there is a little OCD involved. I am attempting to formalize this method for the rest of the team to template the other of the plugins, and I wanted to avoid having to say. "Don't worry about that squiggly, that one is OK." –

Comment: Can you correct your title to either _conversions_ or _conventions_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this syntax error issue is known and marked as Deferred.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760339/valid-javascript-razor-syntax-marked-as-syntax-error

Using the suggested workarounds are good enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

You should move most logic to the controller. Which means the line:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ColumnOrder))
```

should be inside the controller:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ColumnOrder)) ViewBag.Something = ...;
```

In razor, initiate your desired state as javascript variables:

```
var something = "@ViewBag.Something"; //this is a javascript line
```

In my experience, Visual Studio's intellisense work correctly in this case and identifies `@ViewBag.Something` as a razor syntax (but note the double quotes, they belong to javascript, which encloses the string value).

Comment: "@ViewBag.Something" adds breaking codes to the generated code, namely the wrapping "" See my update for an example of what is being generated.